# Почему не удается отловить асинхронную функцию при импорте?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, export

При попытке реализовать экспорт и импорт функции столкнулся с непониманием работы node.js
Есть вот такая часть кода в одном из модулей программы, которую я хочу экспортировать:

```
// ./CSVParser/oneMinuteBaseTimeframeID
const startBaseTimeframesConverting = async function startTimeframesConverting(ticker) {
  const currencyDatabaseName = ticker;
  const currencyMinutesTimeframe = 1;
  const currencySymbol = currencyDatabaseName;
  const currencyTimeframeMinutesTypeSymbol = 'm';

  return await oneMinuteBaseTimeframeID(
      currencyDatabaseName,
      currencyMinutesTimeframe,
      currencySymbol,
      currencyTimeframeMinutesTypeSymbol
  )
}

exports.exportStartBaseTimeframesConverting = startBaseTimeframesConverting();
```

Далее пытаюсь импортировать эту функцию в другом модуле:

```
let fs = require('fs');
const importStartBaseTimeframesConverting = require('./CSVParser/oneMinuteBaseTimeframeID');

async function testExport() {
  console.log(await importStartBaseTimeframesConverting('EURSGD'));
};

testExport ();
```

После чего получаю следующий результат:
console.log(await importStartBaseTimeframesConverting('EURSGD'));
^

```
TypeError: importStartBaseTimeframesConverting is not a function
    at testExport (E:\Progi3\Trading-tester-vanilla-node\HistoryDataParsers\mainParser.js:5:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Progi3\Trading-tester-vanilla-node\HistoryDataParsers\mainParser.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Из того что я интуитивно понимаю(но могу ошибаться) -
я получаю промис обьект(во время экспорта функции) и из за этого не удается вытащить из него данные.
От сюда возникает вопрос:
Почему вообще этот промис возникает если его нет в модуле в котором происходит импорт?
И второй момент - если он возникает почему не удается его корректно обработать с помощью вызова функции с Await расположенном внутри другой асинхронной функции?
И как собственно корректно делать импорт и експорт асинхронных функций в этом случае?

Comment: Потому что вы экспортируете не функцию, а результат ее выполнения `startBaseTimeframesConverting()` Уберите скобки из импорта, тогда будет экспортироваться функция

Comment: Ну во первых если скобки убрать я все равно получаю следующее:
http://joxi.ru/a2XlbBZCp0KR72
А во вторых если без скобок то как тогда параметр передавать в данную функцию?

Comment: Результат выполнения функции положите в переменную и уже консольте переменную. Асинхронная функция возвращает промис, собственно поэтому вы в консоли видите промис. Когда вы функцию вызываете, передавайте ей нужный параметр, как вы это делали в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Асинхронные функции** (помечены ключевым словом **async**) всегда возвращают промис и ведут себя точно так же, как промисы. Соответственно и рассматривать их надо как промисы.

```js
async function fnAsync() {
   return 'async node function'
}

function fnPromise() {
   return Promise.resolve('Promise node function')
}

async function run() {
    console.log(await fnAsync());
    console.log(await fnPromise());
}

run()
```

> С асинхронными функциями можно работать так же через then/catch

```js
async function fnAsync() {
   return 'async node function'
}

async function run() {
    await fnAsync()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data1', data);
            return data + ' 1'
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data2', data);
            return data + ' 1'
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data3', data);
            throw new Error('Что то сломалось в асинхронной функции');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('ERR', err);
            return 'Это сообщение об ошибке'
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data4', data);
        })
}

run()
```

В **node.js** для экспорта функций необходимо отдавать только саму функцию, но не вызывать ее.

```
exports.exportStartBaseTimeframesConverting = startBaseTimeframesConverting;
```

Когда функцию импортировали, ее можно вызывать

```
async function testExport() {
  console.log(await importStartBaseTimeframesConverting('EURSGD'));
};
```

т.к. console.log() не стандартизирован, то для отображения результатов, лучше использовать переменную или вывести результат через .then

```
async function testExport() {
  const x = await importStartBaseTimeframesConverting('EURSGD');
  console.log('RESULT1', x);
  await importStartBaseTimeframesConverting('EURSGD')
    .then( x => console.log('RESULT2', x));
};
```

> Экспорт результата выполнения асинхронной функции

Можно так же переменной присвоить результат выполнения асинхронной функции, экспортировать переменную и работать с ней как с уже завершившимся промисом(главное дождаться его завершения)
Такое бывает полезно, если, допустим, нам надо создать экземпляр класса и уже его экспортировать.

```
// 1.js
// Здесь лежат функция для экспорта и константа с результатом выполнения функции
/**
 * Возвращает текст через заданное время
 * @param {string | number} print
 * @param {number} wait
 * @return {Promise<string | number>}
 */
export async function printText(print = 'Нет данных', wait = 100) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(print);
        }, wait);
    })
}

export const resultPrint = printText();

// 2.js
//Импортируем и вызываем
import { printText, resultPrint } from './1.js'

async function tst() {
    console.log(1, printText(123, 123))
    console.log(2, await printText('456', 200))
    await console.log(3, resultPrint);
    resultPrint.then((data) => {
        console.log('data', data);
        return data + ' then'
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log('data1', data);
        return data
    })
}
```

Итого, при экспорте и импорте функций нет никаких отличий, асинхронная это функция или синхронная.

---

Касательно вопроса, почему у вас в console.log(await function) выдает **promese pendind**, скорее всего старая версия node.js

Ниже пример, где можно увидеть, что console.log() успешно дожидается ответа от промиса, прежде чем вывести результат:

```js
/**
 * Возвращает текст через заданное время
 * @param {string | number} print
 * @param {number} wait
 * @return {Promise<string | number>}
 */
async function printText(print = 'Нет данных', wait = 100) {
return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res(print);
    }, wait);
})
}

async function run() {
printText(10, 400).then(data => console.log('d10', data));
printText(11, 100).then(data => console.log('d11', data));
printText(12, 500).then(data => console.log('d12', data));
printText(13, 300).then(data => console.log('d13', data));
printText(14, 200).then(data => console.log('d14', data));
console.log(1, await printText(1, 200))
console.log(2, await printText(2, 100))
console.log(3, await printText(3, 300))
}

run();
```

Comment: Отличные примеры!
А если необходимо 2 асинхронные функции из разных модулей импортировать(в одном файле) - то каким образом заставить их выполняться поочередно?
Например следующий вариант у меня не работает синхронно:
await m1TimeframeParsing(ticker);
await m1TimeframeTesting(ticker);
Cначала отрабатывает вторая функция и только за ней стартует первая.

Comment: Все тоже самое. Эти обе функции должны быть обернуты в асинхронную функцию. Возможно вам стоит обновить версию node, потому как с ключевым словом await выполнение кода останавливается до тех пор, пока не будет получен ответ.

Comment: Попробовал у себя, await успешно ждет ответа. добавьте console.log() в функцию перед и после каждого вызова, посмотрите на результат. И еще, вот это вот вы зачем делаете `getFiles = async function (dir)` и почему нет инициализации getFiles? делайте `async function getFiles(dir) {}` или `const getFiles = async (dir) => {}`. Оно конечно имеет право на жизнь, но выглядит, как по мне, странновато...

Comment: >> И еще, вот это вот вы зачем делаете getFiles =
опечатался - исправил сейчас )
На счет остального - как проверю отпишусь..

Comment: Проверил - код следующим образом отрабатывает: http://joxi.ru/DmBgybLh6dKOj2 Если вы такой тест имели ввиду конечно. О чем это должно говорить?

Comment: Возможен асинхронный вывод, особенно если это сторонняя библиотека. Посмотрите что возвращается, присвоив результат переменным. Однако это все тема для отдельного вопроса и исследования библиотеки. Точно могу сказать, что ваш код дожидается результата, а уже потом идет дальше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140312/discussion-between-mike-kharkov-and-swad).