# С первого раза не обновляется HTML-таблица

Tags: javascript, html

```
/*получаем данные из питон*/
async function results() {
    let a = await eel.get_data()();
    localStorage.setItem("localData", JSON.stringify(a));
    var mytable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localData')); 
    console.log('Данные из локального хранилища:', mytable);
}
/*вытаскиваем данные из локального хранилища*/
var arr = new Array();
function getData(){
    var str = localStorage.getItem('localData');
    if (str != null) {
    arr = JSON.parse(str);
    }
}
/*отображение данных в таблицу html*/
function showData(){
    results();
    getData();
    const [id, rasp, name, sn, inv] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    var tbl = document.getElementById('table');

    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var r = tbl.insertRow();
        var cell1 = r.insertCell();
        var cell2 = r.insertCell();
        var cell3 = r.insertCell();
        var cell4 = r.insertCell();
        var cell5 = r.insertCell();

        cell1.innerHTML = arr[i][id];
        cell2.innerHTML = arr[i][rasp];
        cell3.innerHTML = arr[i][name];
        cell4.innerHTML = arr[i][sn];
        cell5.innerHTML = arr[i][inv];
    }

}
showData();
/*функция обновления данных в таблице*/
document.querySelector("#update").onclick = function(){
    for (var i = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr').length -1; i; i--) {
        document.getElementById('table').deleteRow(i);
    }
    getData();
    showData();
}
```

Есть вот такой код, я сделал функцию для обновления данных в таблице, на тот случай, если во время использования приложения кто-то внесет данные в бд. Функция работает, но почему-то только при втором нажатии кнопки "Обновить". В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Первая проблема - асинхронность. Вы не дожидаетесь выполнения функции `results();` внутри `showData()`

Comment: @SwaD подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут [про асинхронные функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462342/1462575#1462575)